# Trying to put json responce in a table - undefined error

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a json response from an API which I am trying to put in a table. This is what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/xnj1hwwj/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json = "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=51.4500&lng=-2.5833&username=demo&maxRows=2&radius=5";
  var tr;
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].distance + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
  }
});
```

Any feedback would be appreciated on how I can get this running. I'd rather not use another library for this if I can avoid it.

Comment: `json` is storing a `string` (containing the api call you likely want to make) in your example, not a json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shoud look like this if you want your `json` to have some datas :

```
var url = "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=51.4500&lng=-2.5833&username=demo&maxRows=2&radius=5";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {

        //turn the response into a json object
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        // do whatever you want now


    }
}
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send();
```

You will not be able to make it work in a fiddle because of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content

Comment: I can make it work on jsfiddle by using jsifddle as http and loading jquery over http. However I can't get your code to work. I make the url into a json data and then tried to format it like this but it doesn't return anything. This is a bit beyond my understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/f7cnnctf/3/

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f7cnnctf/5/. The thing is that the variable `data` is an `Object` with a single key called `geonames`. And this key has an array of Objects as value. So you should loop over `data.geonames` which is an array and access `name` and `distance` properties with `data.geonames[i].distance`. I don't know much about jquery but check the console.log

Answer (score 1):

First make an ajax call to get a response:

```js
$.get('http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=51.4500&lng=-2.5833&username=demo&maxRows=2&radius=5', function(json) {
  renderResponse(json, $('#result'), 0);
});
function renderResponse(obj, node, space) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i ++) {
        var inside = obj[keys[i]]
        ,   isWritable = ['string', 'number', 'boolean'].indexOf(typeof inside) != -1
        ,   key = keys[i]
        ,   indentation = Array(space + 1).join('&nbsp;')
        ;
        var prop = $('<div/>', {html: indentation + key + ':&nbsp' + (isWritable ? inside : '[') + '<br>'}).appendTo(node);
        if(!isWritable) {
            renderResponse(inside, prop, space + 8);
            $('<div/>', {html: indentation + ']' + (i < keys.length - 1 ? ',' : '') + '<br>'}).appendTo(prop);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't know why I'm struggling but I cant put it in the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/f7cnnctf/1/

Comment: No Problem. If you inspect element, you can see the error that jsfiddle shows:

`jquery.min.js:5 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/f7cnnctf/1/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=51.4500&lng=-2.5833&username=demo&maxRows=2&radius=5'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Ok I can get it working on jsfiddle now like this: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/f7cnnctf/2/ - However on my example it is shown as a table, but yours is just one per line. How do I make it a table?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Moishe Lipsker in the comments, you don't have an AJAX request, just a URL with a bunch of GET parameters. You should read up on one of the jQuery AJAX methods, such as `$.ajax()` which is required to return the JSON object that you need.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/